Understanding the proof of Perron–Frobenius theorem
I reviewed the proof for Perron–Frobenius' theorem as stated in this article.
In the proof, they define Q to be a positive orthant ( $Q:= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: x \geq 0, x \neq 0 \}$)
For an irreducible matrix T with non-negative elements, define $ P=(I+T)^k $. They state that for large enough k, P is a primitive matrix.
Consider $ L(z) := \max \\{s: sz\leq Tz \\}$ for $z \in Q$
which is same as $L(z) = \min_{1\leq i\leq n, z_i \neq 0}\frac{(Tz)_i}{z_i}$
Now, if $z \leq y, z \neq y$ (they mean element-wise), then $ Pz \le Py$. Also $PT = TP$. So if $sz \leq Tz$, then
$sPz \leq PTz = TPz$
and thus $ L(z) \leq L(Pz) $, which I am unable to understand. How does one come to the final inequality
